# Specman - How can I change the test to be more generic?

Tags: generics, parameters, verification, specman

I have a test which named test_dpwm.

The test contains some code like "

```
    event dpwm_clk_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_dpwm_clk$)@sim;
    event tc_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_tc$)@dpwm_clk_e;

    body()@driver.clock is only {

        message(LOW,"Configure Modules wait states");
        do CONFIG_WAIT_STATE seq keeping {.module=="DPWM_CNT";      .wait_state in [0..3];};
.....
......

        do EN_DPWM_CNT seq keeping {.en==1;};
        do DPWM_TEST seq keeping {.dpwm_idx==0; .hw_en==hw_en; .num_of_cycles==num_of_cycles;};

...
..};
```

I want to create exactly the same test for another dpwm module, which called aux_dpwm....so every each "dpwm" will be "aux_dpwm".
For example above code will become:

```
    event aux_dpwm_clk_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_aux_dpwm_clk$)@sim;
    event tc_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_tc$)@aux_dpwm_clk_e;

    body()@driver.clock is only {

        message(LOW,"Configure Modules wait states");
        do CONFIG_WAIT_STATE seq keeping {.module=="AUX_DPWM_CNT";      .wait_state in [0..3];};
.....
......

        do EN_AUX_DPWM_CNT seq keeping {.en==1;};
        do AUX_DPWM_TEST seq keeping {.aux_dpwm_idx==0; .hw_en==hw_en; .num_of_cycles==num_of_cycles;};

...
..};
```

Is there any generic way to do it by param or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with a macro.
For simplicity, I'll ignore the fact that several places in your example use an upper-case variant of the name, and then a simple `define as` macro is sufficient. With some other trick (maybe involving also a `define as computed` macro) the upper-case usage could also be handled.

```
define <my_test'struct_member> "my_test <module'name>" as {
    event <module'name>_clk_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_<module'name>_clk$)@sim;
    event tc_e is rise (driver.lv_top_env.smp.port_tc$)@<module'name>_clk_e;

    body()@driver.clock is only {

        message(LOW,"Configure Modules wait states");
        do CONFIG_WAIT_STATE seq keeping {.module=="<module'name>_CNT";      .wait_state in [0..3];};
.....
......

        do EN_<module'name>_CNT seq keeping {.en==1;};
        do <module'name>_TEST seq keeping {.<module'name>_idx==0; .hw_en==hw_en; .num_of_cycles==num_of_cycles;};

...
    };
};
```

And then:

```
    my_test dpwm;
```

or:

```
    my_test aux_dpwm;
```

and so on.